# After adding aasm gem, application gives me error: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine, aasm

My model:

```
class Lead < ApplicationRecord

  include AASM

  aasm column: 'status' do
     state :new, initial: true
     state :valid

     event :submit do 
       transitions from: :new, to: :valid
     end 
     ...
  end
  ...

end
```

And the Controller:

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
  @lead = @leads.new lead_params 
  if @lead.save  
    flash[:success] = "Lead saved successfully"
    render 'show'
  end

  ...
end
```

When trying to create a new lead, it gives me error `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`. All this happened after I added `aasm` gem. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found the reason after some hard work. Problem is with how `AASM` gem is built. Here I have used `valid` as a state. That's the problem. Seems like it's a reserved keywork in the gem. Renaming it to another state name solved the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. BUT...I can't rename the state name in this legacy system. I'm getting " WARN -- : WorkOrder: overriding method 'invalid?'!